# SQL API call through sp_OAMethod causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, api

I'm looking to add an item to our systems through an API call to the supplier's site on given conditions.  We have a replicated database and I want the process to be automated.

The supplier's, surprisingly, require you to login on one address then navigate to another to call the SEND but I don't think that the session is being persisted.

The code below is the SP I'm trying to create, which would allow me to use it for a variety of updates, not just this specific type.

The code I have so far is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallAPI]
                        (
                         @Address nvarchar(MAX)
                        ,@Message nvarchar(MAX)
                        )
AS

DECLARE @url_login nvarchar(MAX) = 'https://credentials'
DECLARE @Login nvarchar(MAX) = '{"username": "uSeR","password": "pAsS"}'
DECLARE @obj int
DECLARE @hResult int
DECLARE @statusText varchar(1000)
DECLARE @status varchar(1000) = 200

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Log in
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'post', @url_login, false
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'api-key', 'APIKey'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'connection', 'keep - alive'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'cookie', 'monster'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', NULL, @Login
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'StatusText', @statusText out
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'Status', @status out
IF @status = 200 
    BEGIN
        print 'Successful log-in'
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        --Navigate to required address
        EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'post', @Address, false
        EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'cookie', 'monster'
        EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'StatusText', @statusText out
        EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'Status', @status out
        IF @status = 200 
            BEGIN
                -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                --Post message
                print 'Successful navigate'
                EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', NULL, @Message
                EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'StatusText', @statusText out
                EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'Status', @status out
                IF @status = 200 
                    print 'Successful posting'
            END
    END

IF @status <> 200
    SELECT @status, @statusText 

EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

Comment: Your use of `nvarchar(max)` indicates that you're on a version that supports SQLCLR integration. I'd *seriously* recommend you investigate that route rather than trying to use the painful COM interop functionality.

Comment: Is that the thing where you create a piece of .NET code and call it?  I was hoping that wasn't the answer but can see why it should be.

Comment: Yes, calling out to an external HTTP API is simple from .NET. And the error handling model (exception throwing) is far simpler than all of the `@hResult` checks that you *should* but currently *don't* have in this code.

Comment: your code save me a day thank U so much